# How can I (or should I) transform this DataFrame of DataFrames into a MultiIndexed DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of DataFrames of Series like this:

```
       state1            state2            state3            ...
       sym1  sym2  sym3  sym1  sym2  sym3  sym1  sym2  sym3  ...
date1  1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     ...
date2  10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    ...
date3  19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    ...
...    ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
```

`state1`, `state2`, etc. are all DataFrames for individual states. `sym1`, `sym2`, etc. are all symptom time series. This allows me to do something like this:

```
>>> df['Alabama']['Chills']
2012-07-01     58
2012-07-02     64
2012-07-03     61
2012-07-04     23
2012-07-05     48
2012-07-06     63
2012-07-07     33
2012-07-08     55
2012-07-09     56
2012-07-10     39
2012-07-11     61
2012-07-12     28
2012-07-13     24
2012-07-14     51
2012-07-15     59
2012-07-16     75
2012-07-17     52
2012-07-18     61
2012-07-19     65
2012-07-20     40
2012-07-21     56
2012-07-22     13
2012-07-23     44
2012-07-24     23
2012-07-25     28
2012-07-26     29
2012-07-27     18
2012-07-28     16
2012-07-29     42
2012-07-30     53
             ...
2014-06-02    143
2014-06-03    133
2014-06-04    102
2014-06-05    139
2014-06-06    119
2014-06-07     74
2014-06-08    180
2014-06-09    136
2014-06-10    135
2014-06-11    106
2014-06-12     73
2014-06-13    102
2014-06-14     75
2014-06-15     57
2014-06-16    234
2014-06-17    143
2014-06-18    182
2014-06-19    115
2014-06-20    184
2014-06-21    171
2014-06-22     77
2014-06-23    211
2014-06-24    202
2014-06-25     95
2014-06-26    137
2014-06-27     98
2014-06-28    138
2014-06-29    165
2014-06-30    136
2014-07-01     43
Freq: D, Name: Chills, dtype: int64
```

However, I'm not sure that this is the optimal way to arrange data like this. I was looking at [MultiIndices](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html), which would allow me to do something like this:

```
state1  sym1  date1  1
              date2  10
              date3  19
        sym2  date1  2
              date2  11
              date3  20
        sym3  date1  3
              date2  12
              date3  21
state2  sym1  date1  4
              date2  13
              ...    ...
```

I have 2 questions:

1. What exactly are the benefits of transforming my current data structure to a new data structure that uses MultiIndices? From what I gather, you can effectively store higher dimensional data in a single DataFrame, which reduces redundancy/complexity, which should result in faster operations on a smaller data structure. Is that correct?
2. How exactly can I transform the data structure I already have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, I think you are right, plus Pandas provides convenient indexing methods for hierarchically indexed dataframe, like the Slicers.

Regarding how to convert your data structure to the hierarchically indexed dataframe, first, you need merge your dataframes for each state together to form a horizontal structure, then you can use transpose and stack to rearrange into a vertical structure.

```
In [95]: df
Out[95]: 
      state1           state2           state3          
        sym1 sym2 sym3   sym1 sym2 sym3   sym1 sym2 sym3
0                                                       
date1      1    2    3      4    5    6      7    8    9
date2     10   11   12     13   14   15     16   17   18
date3     19   20   21     22   23   24     25   26   27

In [96]: df.T.stack()
Out[96]: 
state1  sym1  date1     1
              date2    10
              date3    19
        sym2  date1     2
              date2    11
              date3    20
        sym3  date1     3
              date2    12
              date3    21
state2  sym1  date1     4
              date2    13
              date3    22
        sym2  date1     5
              date2    14
              date3    23
        sym3  date1     6
              date2    15
              date3    24
state3  sym1  date1     7
              date2    16
              date3    25
        sym2  date1     8
              date2    17
              date3    26
        sym3  date1     9
              date2    18
              date3    27
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is awesome. In your post, you say, "first, you need merge your dataframes for each state together to form a horizontal structure" - how do I do that? The transpose and stack seems to work all by itself, although accessing elements appears to be really slow.

Comment: Ah ha! I was indexing wrong. Looks like I can pull a time series like this: `df.ix['state1'].ix['sym2']`. I can also grab all time series across each state for a particular symptom by doing `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, ['sym3']]]`. This is really slick. Thanks a ton for your help! Can't believe all it took was `df.T.stack()`.

Comment: Single column (or low) of hierarchially indexed dataframe can be called either from chained selection, like you said, `df.ix['state1'].ix['sym2']` (or `df.state1.sym2`), or called using a 'atomic' indexing tuple, `df[('state1', 'sym2')]'.

Comment: `df.state1.sym2` and `df[('state1', 'sym2')]` both seem to be extremely slow. `df.ix['state1'].ix['sym2']` returns results almost instantly, but the CPU pegs at 100% for the other two methods. Perhaps those indexing methods don't properly utilize the index structure?